# View priority to fill StackView width

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview

I have a `Horizontal StackView`. Later I add 2 views: `UILabel` & `UIButton`.

[image: My current StackView]

Current problem: `UILabel` only takes minimum width, it only takes enough width to show text, `UIButton` take the rest.
[image]
Expected result: `UILabel` take much width as possible while `UIButton` only take enough width to show its text.

I tried to add left constraint for `UILabel`, right for `UIButton` but no luck.
What i tried:

- Option 1: Fix the `UIButton` width, then `UILabel` takes the rest, but not good in multi language.
- Option 2: Let `UIButton` takes the width, but set its align to the right. But its limitation is clicking range too large.

This is what i expected:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Decrease the label’s content hugging priority.

Comment: @matt Thanks. It works! Can you provide an official answer so I can accept it? Thanks.